# swift search bar bugs?

Tags: swift, searchbar

The below search bar function runs 2 times if I input the search bar text field as the image and delete the text by using back space button of the keyboard. 
I would like to explain more about the input, if i just input English and press the back space button form the keyboard, it works fine. but If I try to input chinese and press back space button before confirming the chinese character. This function will execute 2 times.
Please kindly help and explain this issue. Thank you very much!

[image]

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        pub.removeAll()
        retrieveData()
        print("11111")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: search bar delegate to the viewcontroller and every fuction of search bar is working well. Only this function has problem.

Comment: I would like to explain more about the input, if i just input English and press the back space button form the keyboard, it works fine. but If I try to input chinese and press back space button before confirming the chinese character. This function will execute 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

It will run twice because:

1. The text does change when you add a character in the search text field. Example - sgdgd
2. The text does change when you remove a character from the search text field.
   Example - sgdg

Comment: this function will only execute when text.count == 0, so it should be only run 1 time.